# how to use the BayesSearchCV optimization function on LSTM

Tags: python, optimization, lstm

I am a beginner in the field of deep learning. I would like to optimize an LSTM model used for time series prediction.
I used the BayesSearchCV optimization function and found the following error:
layers is not a legal parameter
I would like to know if my code is correct and how I can solve this problem.

Thanks

```
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from skopt.space import Integer


search_space = {
     "units": Integer(low=1, high=60, name= 'units'),
     "batch_size": Integer(low=1, high=234, name= 'batch_size'),
     "layers": Integer(low=0,high =10, name= 'layers'),
     "epochs": Integer(low= 40, high= 60, name='epochs' )
}

def f_model(search_space):
    
    model = Sequential()
    if search_space['layers'] == 1:
        model.add(LSTM(units=search_space['units'],input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))

    else:
        model.add(LSTM(units=search_space['units'], return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))        
        for i in range(search_space['layers']-2):
            model.add(LSTM(units=search_space['units'],return_sequences=True))
        
        model.add(LSTM(units=search_space['units']))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    
    result = model.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=0, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=params['batch_size'],epochs=params['epochs'])
    
    validation_loss = np.argmin(result.history['val_loss']) 
    return {validation_loss}

model=KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_clf)

def on_step(optim_result):
    score = forest_bayes_search.best_score_
    print("best score: %s" % score)
    if score < 0.001:
        print('Interrupting!')
        return True

forest_bayes_search = BayesSearchCV(model, search_space, n_iter=32, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
forest_bayes_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```